# Elements inside viewpagers` fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a problem. I have a viewpager with 3 fragments inside. In first fragment i have some ImageViews.

**First** of all how make that imageviews visible with timer? I used thise code below but i have **error which looks like: variable 'mImageView' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared class.**

```
mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
                 mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
}, 5000);
```

How can i solve this problem?

**Second** I tried to move that elements (ImageViews) by X values when user start scrolling from first fragment to next fragment. It works but when i go to last 3-d fragment app crash. So why it happen?!

**MainActivity.java**

```
pager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                // transformation here
                final float normalizedPosition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
                page.setAlpha(normalizedPosition);

                int pageWidth = page.getWidth();

                if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                    page.setAlpha(0);

                } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                    mImageView.setTranslationX((float) (-(1 - position) * 1.7 * pageWidth));


                    mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 5000);

                    // The 0.5, 1.5 values you see here are what makes the view move in a different speed.
                    // The bigger the number, the faster the view will translate.
                    // The result float is preceded by a minus because the views travel in the opposite direction of the movement.

                }
                else{ // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                    page.setAlpha(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Third:** Is it possible to make move elements by circle when user scroll. Need any help!

Comment: One question at a time is probably a best way to get proper answers...

Comment: For the first issue, add a final modifier to mImageView. For 2), could you post your logcat to see the error?. For 3) What do you mean with "move by circle" ?

Comment: Hello guys! how looks that final modifier. As a matter of fact i make my first steps in android programming. Error in logcat start with this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setTranslationX(float)' on a null object reference e.t.c... 3-d one check this example (2-d fragment here exactly what i want): https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*-L1wQm6Ces3nKZGPkOcAJg.gif

Comment: `View page` is a *page* of your `ViewPager`. `(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)` is part of your Activity

Comment: @Blackbelt you want to say i must to write these codes in each Fragment java documents?

Comment: no. What I meant was that you probably need to use the page argument

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, as I said in the comment, you need to make the mImageView variable final

```
final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Then, the null pointer exception, is probably caused (as Blackbelt said), because you're using the activity's findViewById method, and probably the imageView you need is in the fragment view:

```
final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

And for your 3º question, please explain what you mean by "move by circle", then I'll update my post(if I can) with an answer.

Comment: i added final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); as you said but app crashed from the start and logcat error is the same as before. About 3 my question. Can you look this source its a picture. Here lets say sun and moon (images) move by this lines (---) when user scroll. https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/dW_vFUWiye6d3ETelTFkIaj5E9o=/1020x0/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/2811436/Photo_Jan_06__4_29_14_PM.1389114747.png

Comment: In which layout do you have the imageView? Can you add the code where you inflate the layout, and the XML of that layout?  And for the 3º question, if you target API LV >= 11, you can use a ValueAnimator, and set a ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener (then in there, you can implement the translation using trigonometry)

Comment: What are TabFragment2 and TabFragment3 ? If they all are like TabFragment1, it must work (I compiled and tested your code) (And you should have edited your original post instead of writing an new anwer)

Comment: its really strange and interesting how it work in your case, cause in my case it crashed and logcat error is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setTranslationX(float)' on a null object reference. I really don`t know what to do now. Can you write your transformPage method? Is it same as mine?!

Comment: You didn't answered what TabFragment2 and TabFragment3 are. The only difference in what I tested was that inside the ViewPagerAdapter's getItem(...), I had always the same Fragment being instantiated.

Comment: I wrote it before I thought. For each page i had there own TabFragment. 1-st layout had TabFragment1, 2-nd TabFragment2 and last 3-d had TabFragment3. Is it need that it will work only if i will have 1 fragment for all pages as you?

Comment: No it's not, but the problem is that I suspect your other two fragments are using different layouts which don't have an ImageView with ID imageView2. Otherwise it should work

Comment: I checked all ID that i used in my layouts and they are different. And Fragments use different layouts. Its riddle now for me. Anyway Thanks for spend your time for me.

Comment: Not sure if you could fix the problem. But if you're using differnet layouts, and some of them DO NOT have an ImageView with ID imageView2, then it's expected to fail, as page.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); will return null for those fragments, and well... then you'll have a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int PAGES = 3;
    private String[] titles={"News", "Organizations", "Map"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TabFragment1();
            case 1:
                return new TabFragment2();
            case 2:
                return new TabFragment3();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The item position should be less or equal to:" + PAGES);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }
}
```

As you see for each page I have individual fragment documents. Here below one of them:

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_tab_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/city"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```